# Nested Objects, accessing array of objects in parent objects = undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have a javascript object (data from MySQL) that has a property that is an array of objects, for example;

```
parentObject = { ID: "1", 
                 Desc: "A description",
                 childObjectArray : [ { item: "an item", cost: "cost" },
                                      { item: "another item", cost: "another cost" } ]
               };
```

My problem is that when I pass `parentObject` to a function I can see it, but if I try to access `parentObject.childObjectArray` I get `undefined`.  I can happily access `parentObject.ID` and `parentObject.Desc`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: additional info and sample code:

Code from Angular controller (have tried without the `hasOwnProperty` bit and no difference in result):

```
    this.doStuff = function() {
        for (parentObject in this.parentObjects) {
            if (this.parentObjects.hasOwnProperty(parentObject)) {
                myService.doStuff(this.parentObjects[parentObject]);
            }                    
        }
    };
```

Code from Angular service that is called by the controller:

```
function doStuff (obj) {
    console.log(obj);                      // looks good, can see parent and child object
    console.log(obj.childObjectArray);     // results in 'undefined'
    console.log(obj.childObjectArray[0]);  // still 'undefined'
};
```

Comment: Surely it is not just as simple as using `parentObject.ChildObjectArray`, not `parent.ChildObjectArray`?

Comment: parentObject.ChildObjectArray[0] should give you a first ChildObjectArray item

Comment: Exactly what I thought, but if I use `parentObject.ChildObjectArray[0]` or `parentObject.ChildObjectArray` I always get `undefined`, yet if I `console.log(parentObject);` I can see the child array of objects

Comment: @gregl - typo in original post, corrected

Comment: It looks like you're missing the relevant code. Try to come up with the smallest reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: From what you've shown us, there's no reason for it not to work. As @nrabinowitz mentions, you should look at narrowing down your problem, preferably following the advice in [mcve], and you may find the answer yourself, or at the very least, come up with an example we can run, and see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: you're missing a `var` for your `parentObject`.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow has something called Stack Snippets, available by clicking the icon that looks like a page with curly brackets, that can help with this process.

Comment: Of course this can't work. You're passing the property values (like `"1"`, `"A description"`, and `[…]`) to your `doStuff` function. None of these have a `childObjectArray` property. Just use `myService.doStuff(this.parentObjects)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for suggestions - after trying to produce a concise working example of the problem I managed to figure out why it was going wrong....

Basically the child object array is populated via a $http call, which (you've probably already guessed) had not returned by the time I was calling my other service method.

A bit of re-work on the code to ensure the $http call had returned the values first and 
, hey presto, it worked :-)